# How to deploy a VB.NET solution with multiple projects

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, publish

I work in visual studio 2012 and make VB.NET applications frequently but the applications I make are usually small scale and only have one project within the solution. So I just package these into a click once deployment and and publish it out. But recently I have started working on a solution that has over 50 different projects (various custom controls/dll's, windows forms, data models, etc.) Each project points at different components of other projects and thus has a reference to them.

So my question is, what is the correct procedure to push out a package for a user to run an application that has this many projects? There is a main startup project that runs first so do I just deploy that project and everything will be packaged in it? How do I make sure all the custom dll's are being deployed? I've also though maybe making an MSI would help encapsulate all the components that need to be installed? I've tried researching this topic but I didn't find too much information about it.

Comment: What is the user actually going to execute?  Is it just an application which references other class libraries?  The output of those class libraries would be included when you publish the application.  What happens when you try to publish the application like you normally would any other?

Comment: Like I said there is a main project that runs first. This project is just a windows form. But from this form, other projects that are also windows forms can be opened. 

For instance: we have project1  that has form1 and project2 that has form2. project1 also has a reference to dll_1 and project2 has references to dll_2. When a button is clicked on form1, form2 from project2 is opened. So I can publish project1 and it has the correct references to project2 and dll_1. But I also need references to dll_2 because project2 points at it. So just publishing project1 doesn't seem right.

Comment: Are these projects separate applications?  How does the main application run them?

Comment: These ties get even deeper because there are over 50 projects that are various windows forms and custom dll's

Comment: It has a reference to the other projects and then opens their forms through the class reference

Comment: So you have one application project which references other class libraries?  And what happens when you publish that project?

Comment: I've never tried it. I've never worked with a solution this big and with this many projects. So that's what I was trying to figure out in my original question. What is the correct way to deploy this? Just publish that first startup project and it should capture everything?

Comment: Unless the references are in some way broken, deployment would include the referenced libraries.  You really could *at least try*.  If you encounter an actual problem, we can help with that.  But not wanting to even try isn't something we can help with.

Comment: Never said I didn't want to try. Was just curious if there is a correct way to go about it. But I'll go ahead and see what happens with a click once deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Only one application can be the "startup project". You should be able to choose which one is the startup project for the ClickOnce application manifest. If you want to have multiple different executables, make different manifests.

One option is to create a project that integrates the others into some sort of launcher. But fundamentally, a ClickOnce application manifest must lead to a *single* executable. That executable may have one or more referenced libraries 
or additional projects that will be automatically included during the deployment process.